# How to pass objects from Client to Map and Reduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Is that the class should extend ObjectWritable class? Then how can I pass it from client to the Map and Reduce? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean to pass an object from your client code to your Mappers and Reducers?

You will have to use some form of serialization to do that, since the data is going over the wire. There are a few possibilities depending on your scenario:

1. Probably the best solution would be to instantiate the object in the Mappers/Reducers. To pass the information required for the constructor call, you can use the Job-Configuration.

   ```
   conf.setInt("foo", 32);
   conf.set("bar", "bazz");
   ```
2. If your object is serializable and quite small you can serialize it and include a base64 encoded version of it in the JobConf.
3. If the serialized objects are to big, you can use the distributed cache: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html#DistributedCache

Comment: Check this [article](http://www.lexemetech.com/2008/07/rpc-and-serialization-with-hadoop.html) on the comparison of the different serialization frameworks which can be used with Hadoop. Compression might also be considered, if the object is huge.